# Как сделать цикл для сопоставления значений, с проверкой

Tags: java

Идея вроде этого

```
for(Long id : ids){
  if(id.equals("нужное значение"){
    //действие
    System.out.print("ввух, получилось")
  }
}
```

и вот после добавить что если цикл закончился а действие не произошло то выдать ошибку или вывести что то в консоль. Пытался сделать с boolean matched, но у меня не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boolean succeeded = false;
for (Long id : ids) {
  if (id.equals("нужное значение")) {
    //действие
    succeeded = true;
    System.out.print("ввух, получилось");
  }
}
if (!succeeded) {
    System.out.print("Ничего не вышло(");
}
```

Comment: я считал что если она сработало, и успех = тру, то это значение локальное в цикле и за циклом оно не будет видно, ну я наверное ошибаюсь, сейчас попробую

Comment: сработало, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean matched = false;
for(Long id : ids){
  if(id.equals("нужное значение")) { // !!! add missing parentheses
    //действие
    System.out.print("ввух, получилось"); // !!! add missing semicolon
    matched = true;
  }
}
if (!matched) {
  // выдать ошибку 
}
```

Comment: спасибо, сработало